# Partition ByteArray to equally ByteArray of Queue

Tags: java, android, arrays, kotlin

So, I have a ByteArray of **dynamic size** from the server and I need to divide it into **15 equal size** and add it to my `Queue<ByteArray>`. So how do I do this?

I need this for my BLE device actually. I'm doing a firmware update and I need to convert the bytearray into equally 20 bytes each inside the Queue so that it happens smoothly?

for example bytearray received from the server is 256. I want to have my

```
queue[0]=bytes[0-15] onpeek() 
queue[1]=bytes[16-30] onPeek()
queue[2]=bytes[31-45]onPeek()
 ...
....
queue[n]= bytes[240-255] onPeek()
```

My code:

```
private val sendQueue: Queue<ByteArray> = ConcurrentLinkedQueue()

    @Volatile
    private var isWriting = false


    fun send(
        dataByte: ByteArray,
        gatt: BluetoothGatt
    ): Int {
        var data = dataByte
        while (data.count() > 15) {

//            todo divide into 20 equal byte array and add it to sendQueue.
           
        }
        sendQueue.add(data)

        if (!isWriting) _send(gatt)
        return 0 //0
    }
```

Comment: Who says that your array length divides evenly to 15?

Comment: @GhostCat can you see the edit I have. I guess I'm clear now?

Comment: No, I do not understand how 3 arrays with 15 bytes each result in 256 bytes.

Comment: @GhostCat it will keep increasing. The arrays until the match is found. Actually.

Comment: Sorry, that still doesnt make sense to me. Trey to write super simple sentences. subject verb object. give us a "complete" example. 3 * 15 isnt 256.

Comment: @GhostCat say you receive a byte array of size 10000. And you need to convert that into any collection(Queue) but each item in the collection should be a bye array of  maximum size 15 with a part of the original bytearray. So on traversing all the elements in the collection you get the original byte array from the server.

Comment: So you divide 10000 / 15 ... you get 666 arrays with 15 bytes, and 1 with 10 bytes. Simple maths. Is that what you are asking for?

Comment: @GhostCat yes. How do I do in my code is what I'm asking.

Comment: You do `data.count() / 15` to get to the number of 15 byte arrays. Then you either multiply yourself, or you use the remainder operator (%) to know how many bytes you need in that last array. Then you create those elements accordingly, and loop over it, put in your bytes for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this (draft, not checking)

```
var partCount = 20;
var data = dataByte;
var len = data.getLength();
var partSize = len / partCount;  
for (int i = 0; i < partCount - 1; i++) {    
    var newArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, i * partSize, (i + 1) * partSize);
    sendQueue.add(newArray);
}
// and we added last part (may be a little bigger then other parts if "len % 20 != 0").
var newArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, partSize * (partCount - 1), len); 
sendQueue.add(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if understood your question but this can give a direction

```
dataByte.asIterable().chunked(15).forEach { 
    // 'it' is a List<Byte>, convert it to ByteArray in order to add it to queue.
    sendQueue.add(it.toByteArray())
}
```

referring dataByte as `Iterable` will allow you to [chunk](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html#chunked) it to the size you want,
then all you need is to iterate over it's results and add it to your queue.

Comment: I think getting bytearray of list is different from the elements inside the byte array of the list. So this might not work.